# How can I use JonkyKong/SideMenu - SideMenuPresentationStyle.menuSlideIn?

Tags: side-menu

import SideMenu

class SideMenuConfigurator {

```
static func configure() {
    let leftMenuViewController = LeftMenuViewController.xibInstance()
    SideMenuManager.default.leftMenuNavigationController = SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: leftMenuViewController)

    SideMenuManager.default.menuPresentMode = .menuSlideIn //Deprecated
    SideMenuManager.default.menuFadeStatusBar = true
    SideMenuManager.default.menuAnimationBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear //Deprecated
    SideMenuManager.default.menuWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8 //Deprecated
}
```

}

Comment: Please share your code what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please do not post images of code, copy your code into the question with block code format:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok, just moment

Comment: After few hours of searching solution, I've got it.
In swift 5 and Xcode 11 we have to do next steps to configure SideMenu:

let leftMenuViewController = LeftMenuViewController.xibInstance()
var sideMenuSet = SideMenuSettings()

    SideMenuManager.default.leftMenuNavigationController = SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: leftMenuViewController, settings: sideMenuSet)

sideMenuSet.presentationStyle.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
sideMenuSet.presentationStyle = .menuSlideIn
sideMenuSet.menuWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8

Answer (score 3):

SideMenu vision 6.4.8

Swift 5

Please set presentationStyle in SideMenuSettings and assign it to SideMenuNavigationController.

```
func makeSettings() -> SideMenuSettings{
var settings = SideMenuSettings()
settings.allowPushOfSameClassTwice = false
settings.presentationStyle = .menuSlideIn
settings.statusBarEndAlpha = 0
return settings}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   guard let sideMenuNavigationController = segue.destination as? SideMenuNavigationController else { return }
    sideMenuNavigationController.settings = makeSettings()
```

}

Answer (score 1):

After few hours of searching solution, I've got it.
In swift 5 and Xcode 11 we have to do next steps to configure SideMenu:

```
let leftMenuViewController = LeftMenuViewController.xibInstance()
var sideMenuSet = SideMenuSettings()

SideMenuManager.default.leftMenuNavigationController = 
SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: leftMenuViewController,settings: sideMenuSet)

sideMenuSet.presentationStyle.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear 
sideMenuSet.presentationStyle = .menuSlideIn
sideMenuSet.menuWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8
```

Comment: Kindly can you explain me, in which class you put this code? I am getting troubled to show side menu with slide In.

Comment: @MuhammadDanishQureshi I know this post was a year ago, but I have a problem too with slide in, did you remember if you found a solution?

Comment: @EmadKhalil i did not found solution for it, I removed the library and added custom tableview for slide In. I also used the UIWindow to bring tableview at top.

Comment: @MuhammadDanishQureshi ok great, thanks for your help!